# command for sent mail in outlook web app addin

Tags: outlook, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Recently I tried the outlook web app add-in in visual studio 2015. It's cool one It purely based on the Java script commands. My ultimate motivation i need add one button in add-in if user click that button I need the save the mail my database and send that mail to the recipient.

I am able to fetch the data and saving to my database is successful but unable to trigger send option in add-in. There is any java script command available. Actually I have achieved the same scenario in outlook windows application.

Comment: No, I haven't got any update on this

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send the email using the new [Outlook REST APIs](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi) specifically we have an api for [sending emails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#create-and-send-messages). In addition, to close the compose form, you can use the [Office.context.mailbox.item.close()](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html) To close the mail or calendar item in compose.

Comment: @Manivannan  did you try this? It looks perfect for me. I want to gather some data on an async dialog and use it compose & send an email on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to send the email from server side logic using EWS (exchange web services) see [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp160952.aspx) or you can authenticate with [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-adal-sso-authentication/) and invoke the [outlook REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createandsendmessages)

Comment: Using EWS in fine way but after send I need to close current compose window. I to do it?

Comment: I do not think you can do that.

Comment: You can use the Office.context.mailbox.item.close() To close the mail or calendar item in compose in the Javascript APIs for Outlook Web Add-ins.